# make cell of listview editable in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make a form with listview in c# where i want to enter some text in the cell of listview after double clicking on it.Since i am using visual studio 2013.Is there any way to make cell of listview editable in visual studio 2013?Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Do you want to edit a listview in asp.net?

Comment: Or in Winforms?WÜF? Don't be shy, tell us! It has nothing to do with VS but all with the platform you target. In winforms you can only edit the 1st Item..

Comment: You can't do that without extending the Listview with an edit control you write yourself. Depending on your other design needs, the usual solution is to use a DataGridView instead.